# Why does my Tornado/Flask server choke and die on Windows when hammering it with requests?

Tags: python, sockets, flask, tornado

I have a simple test application on Windows - Tornado running a Flask wsgi application. I can start the server just fine and connect through my web browser and that's just cool.

I can run my performance test, and on my machine I get ~900-1000 requests per second. However, after about 20,000 requests, my server stops responding and my test reports 0 per second. I can try to connect through the web browser, but nothing. Typically <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> has some issues, too (having to hit it several times before refreshing the page in the browser will end the server like normally).

So why does my server choke and die when I hammer on it like this?

Okay, so in the process of trying to rule out different factors - I was able to hit the server from a different machine, even though my local machine was barfing so it looks like it's actually my local machine that's running out of ports or something?

Anyway, here's my code:

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Hey, it's working"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

**tornado_server.py**

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from server import app

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**perftest.py**

```
from socket import *
import time

n = 0
stop = False

from threading import Thread
def monitor():
    global n, stop
    while not stop:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n, 'reqs/sec')
        n = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Thread(target=monitor).start()
    while True:
        try:
            sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.connect(('localhost', 5000))
            sock.send(b'''GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n''')
            resp = sock.recv(4096)
            sock.close()
            n += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            stop = True
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: I *know* that the title is probably a bit misleading, since I now know it's not Flask/Tornado with the problem. But I figure if someone has a similar problem then this title will be more helpful in drawing them in so they'll be able to see, "Surprise! The problem is actually probably not where you thought it was"

Comment: Looks like Beazley's code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Good eye - just watched part of his talk falling asleep last night, and it happened to be perfect timing. 'Course he was using a mac in the demo so no problems. I just dumped my perftest on a linux box and hammered my server but no socket issues. Went a lot slower, though, since it wasn't local. And now that I think about it I was doing a DNS resolve instead of the IP address direct. So it's looking like the issue has to do with Windows sockets. I'm not surprised :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running out of ports. Every connection you make blocks a port and it takes some time to close them, on Windows longer than on other operating systems. As a symptom is should work gain after some time, but only shortly.

You can check that with `netstat`.

Comment: Looks like that's the case - netstat shows a ton of ports in `TIME_WAIT`. Why wouldn't the `sock.close()` call close the sockets off, though? I added an `e` to count errors, and until they stop connecting I don't see any errors.

Comment: Will the `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` option help in this case?